# Logging into an off branch of a site using cURL for c++

Tags: c++, libcurl

I wrote this piece of code to automate a mundane activity i have to do everyday,
the first step is to log into the site so i wrote some simple cURL code and i got that to work by POSTing the required fields

```
#include<curl/curl.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

void main()
{
    string readBuffer,readBuffer2,url,url2;
    url = "https://example/login/index.php";
    auto curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,url.c_str());
        
        istringstream iss(readBuffer);
        vector<string> c;

        do {
            string word;
            iss >> word;
            c.push_back(word);
        } while (iss);
        string check = "name=\"logintoken\"" ;
        string token;
        for (int i=200;i<c.size(); i++)
        {
            if (c[i] == check)
                token =c[i+1];
        }
        cout << token;
        string finaltoken;
        for (int i = token.size() - 3; i > 6; i--)
        {
            finaltoken = token[i]+finaltoken;
        }
        string adds = "logintoken="+finaltoken+"&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD";
        readBuffer = readBuffer + "\n--------------------------------------------------";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, adds.c_str());
        
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    cout<< readBuffer;
}
```

Im able to login fine to the main landing page of the site with this, but my task requires me to go to an off branch of this site.

The way i decided to work around this was instead of going to the login page and doing multiple GETs was to go directly to the off branch link https://example/mod/attendance/view.php?id="some number". as i would be logged out it would ask me to login and id be redirected to the page where i want to be at. **For some reason im not able to login and i cant figure out why i can login from the main  page but not from the other pages.** (i can log in to off branches via browser though)
Using chromes webdev tools there isnt any difference in the POSTed data for both logins
any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, turns out you just need to use the COOKIEJAR method to store the cookies.

So i logged in to the main page once and used the cookies from that session to login to the off branch page like so

```
#include<curl/curl.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include<vector>


using namespace std;

static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

void main()
{
    string readBuffer,readBuffer2,url,url2;
    url = "https://example/login/index.php";
    url2 = "https://example/mod/attendance/view.php?id=no";
    auto curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

        

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        

        
        
        istringstream iss(readBuffer);
        vector<string> c;

        do {
            string word;

            iss >> word;

            c.push_back(word);

        } while (iss);
        string check = "name=\"logintoken\"" ;
        string token;
        for (int i=200;i<c.size(); i++)
        {
            if (c[i] == check)
                token =c[i+1];
            
        }
        cout << token;
        string finaltoken;
        for (int i = token.size() - 3; i > 6; i--)
        {
            finaltoken = token[i]+finaltoken;
        }
        string adds = "logintoken="+finaltoken+"&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD";
        readBuffer = "";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, adds.c_str());
        
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, url.c_str());
        
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        readBuffer = "";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url2.c_str());
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    cout<< readBuffer;
}
```